# SignalR Redis Backplane Group synchronization

Tags: redis, signalr, signalr-backplane

Does SignalR backplane Sync connected groups as in Groups.Add across servers? I know it publishes messages but its not clear if groups are also synced.Essentially I want to know if a server goes down in a web farm will the other servers have the same groups configured?

If so is there any documentation to support this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the backplane does maintain groups, it adds the serverid to group, so you essentially have a group of groups. The parent group being the serverid in the the farm. Its not explained well, but you can find the explanation here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Search in the comments for group, you will see a bit more of a detailed explanation, but its not great.

Comment: This is the only reference to group in the comments and its not clear what its referencing: Continue.One store client (SignalR client) connecting the WebRole representing one store and the WebRole instance it connected to puts the connectionId and storeID as groupName into Hub Groups and using Clients.Group(name).send(). Then the client receives only the message for that store but only from that server instance. Until I have more such clients connecting to other server instances, each client starts to receive messages for its store but from all 3 server instances.

Comment: Basically what it is saying is that, You have a group based on the server in the farm, so your messages would be broadcast to Clients.serverGroup.userGroup. so that the message does not get broadcasted to each client multiple times. So when one server fails, the userGroups would fail over to a new serverGroup. So yes, it will maintain your groups. As for documentation... not much more to go on for that. I think that is the way it is intended to work, I cannot tell if the last part of your comment is what you are experiencing or pasted from somewhere else